# how to pass value between tabpages and activate the other

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tabpage1 with usercontrol1 and tabpage2 with usercontrol2.

i would like to pass int ID from usercontrol1(tabpage1) to usercontrol2(tabpage2) and activate tabpage2.

which tabpage properties and methods shall I use?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, controls should not need to be aware of sibling controls - they know about their parent and any children only (the notable exception to this is radio button controls...). As a result, the form that contains your user controls should be responsible for passing the value from one to the other, for example:

```
usercontrol2.ID = usercontrol1.ID
```

If this needs to occur because the user has interacted with `usercontrol1`, provide an event that can be used to do this:

```
// this is probably automatically handled by the designer
usercontrol1.Click += new EventHandler(usercontrol1_Click);

void usercontrol1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    usercontrol2.ID = usercontrol1.ID
}
```

---

You can activate a specific tab in a tab control by calling `SelectTab()` with the tab you want to activate:

```
tabControl.SelectTab(tabMyTab2);
```

This can also go inside the event handler above. (It cannot be called from a different thread, so putting it in an event handler will avoid any risk of that occurring.)

Comment: my main form load usercontrol1 at runtime, how can i call the main tabcontrol to activate the tab in usercontrol1(let's say button1_clck event)

Comment: @Kiddo I'm not sure how your tab control and your user control are related here - if you're using a standard tab control then the second part of my answer will work in any event handler. If you're using a non-standard tab control you need to provide much more information.

Comment: my mainform.cs is under same root as 'tabs' folder which contains a bunch of user controls. i have problems with usercontrol1 event handlers accessing mainform.tabControl since it is set as private

Comment: @Kiddo Your events on `usercontrol1` should have event handlers that belong to `mainform` - that's what the second code block in my answer is (kind of) showing (it belongs in mainform.cs, not in usercontrol1.cs). You will run into far more problems than it's worth if usercontrol1 can call directly into mainform - it should be the other way around, but events are a way that usercontrol1 can *tell* mainform to do something (if it has a handler).

Comment: @Kiddo Also, have a look at the related questions down the right hand side. I can see at least three that will be helpful (not all of them will, since it sounds like you're not actually using the standard `TabControl`).